# get 'X-Total-Count' from API response

Tags: typescript, flutter, http-headers, response-headers

I'm introducing paging to my web app. I have an API endpoint to get a list of card batches that I use to send a limit and offset through the URL as parameters, which is functioning fine.

I just need to be able to get the total number of batches (not just the number of batches received in the response), so I'm trying to get the total number of rows in my table BEFORE I set LIMIT and OFFSET.

I have researched X-Total-Count in the header as a way to do this, but I'm not sure how to go about implementing it. Do I need to include something on the API call, in the server or both? Looking for a point to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the total count header programmatically using the web back end technology. Assuming you are using express:

```js
res.append('X-Total-Count', totalCountOfNumberOfRows)
```

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

There is no real magic to this, it is header object with a custom header name and value.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i'm using typescript for the backend/api